# 3D curvefitting

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, maple, mplot3d

I have discrete regular grid of `a,b` points and their corresponding `c` values and I interpolate it further to get a smooth curve. Now from interpolation data, I further want to create a polynomial equation for curve fitting. How to fit 3D plot in polynomial?

I try to do this in MATLAB. I used Surface fitting toolbox in MATLAB (r2010a) to curve fit 3-dimensional data. But, how does one find a formula that fits a set of data to the best advantage in MATLAB/MAPLE or any other software. Any advice? Also most useful would be some real code examples to look at, PDF files, on the web etc.

This is just a small portion of my data.

```
a = [ 0.001 .. 0.011];

b = [1, .. 10];

c = [ -.304860225, .. .379710865];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To fit a curve onto a set of points, we can use [ordinary least-squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) regression. There is a [solution page](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1AVW5/) by MathWorks describing the process.

As an example, let's start with some random data:

```
% some 3d points
data = mvnrnd([0 0 0], [1 -0.5 0.8; -0.5 1.1 0; 0.8 0 1], 50);
```

As [@BasSwinckels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552769/97160) showed, by constructing the desired [design matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix), you can use [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) or [`pinv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html) to [solve the overdetermined system](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html#f4-2064) expressed as `Ax=b`:

```
% best-fit plane
C = [data(:,1) data(:,2) ones(size(data,1),1)] \ data(:,3);    % coefficients

% evaluate it on a regular grid covering the domain of the data
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(-3:.5:3, -3:.5:3);
zz = C(1)*xx + C(2)*yy + C(3);

% or expressed using matrix/vector product
%zz = reshape([xx(:) yy(:) ones(numel(xx),1)] * C, size(xx));
```

Next we visualize the result:

```
% plot points and surface
figure('Renderer','opengl')
line(data(:,1), data(:,2), data(:,3), 'LineStyle','none', ...
    'Marker','.', 'MarkerSize',25, 'Color','r')
surface(xx, yy, zz, ...
    'FaceColor','interp', 'EdgeColor','b', 'FaceAlpha',0.2)
grid on; axis tight equal;
view(9,9);
xlabel x; ylabel y; zlabel z;
colormap(cool(64))
```

[image: 1st_order_polynomial]

---

As was mentioned, we can get higher-order polynomial fitting by adding more terms to the independent variables matrix (the `A` in `Ax=b`).

Say we want to fit a quadratic model with constant, linear, interaction, and squared terms (1, x, y, xy, x^2, y^2). We can do this manually:

```
% best-fit quadratic curve
C = [ones(50,1) data(:,1:2) prod(data(:,1:2),2) data(:,1:2).^2] \ data(:,3);
zz = [ones(numel(xx),1) xx(:) yy(:) xx(:).*yy(:) xx(:).^2 yy(:).^2] * C;
zz = reshape(zz, size(xx));
```

There is also a helper function [`x2fx`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/x2fx.html) in the Statistics Toolbox that helps in building the design matrix for a couple of model orders:

```
C = x2fx(data(:,1:2), 'quadratic') \ data(:,3);
zz = x2fx([xx(:) yy(:)], 'quadratic') * C;
zz = reshape(zz, size(xx));
```

Finally there is an excellent function [`polyfitn`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn) on the File Exchange by John D'Errico that allows you to specify all kinds of polynomial orders and terms involved:

```
model = polyfitn(data(:,1:2), data(:,3), 2);
zz = polyvaln(model, [xx(:) yy(:)]);
zz = reshape(zz, size(xx));
```

[image: 2nd_order_polynomial]

Comment: How can I perform same kind of operation in python..!? Bit help would be appreciating... @Amro

Comment: @diffracteD: I translated the code into Python: https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/1db8d69b4b65e8bc66a6

Comment: Thanks for your help... i'll surely try it.. !

Comment: (asking about your github code) is it logical to go for a higher order polynomial fitting to evaluate the surface ?

Comment: @diffracteD: yes you can, although you should be [cautious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge's_phenomenon) of fitting models that are too high of an order..

Comment: ok. Can you suggest me a way to get the minima/maxima value from the fitted surface using the python code ? thank you.

Comment: @diffracteD: Please create a new question, formulate your problem, and link to this post and gist code.

Answer (score 3):

There might be some better functions on the file-exchange, but one way to do it by hand is this:

```
x = a(:); %make column vectors
y = b(:);
z = c(:);

%first order fit
M = [ones(size(x)), x, y];
k1 = M\z; 
%least square solution of z = M * k1, so z = k1(1) + k1(2) * x + k1(3) * y
```

Similarly, you can do a second order fit:

```
%second order fit
M = [ones(size(x)), x, y, x.^2, x.*y, y.^2];
k2 = M\z;
```

which seems to have numerical problems for the limited dataset you gave. Type `help mldivide` for more details.

To make an interpolation over some regular grid, you can do like so:

```
ngrid = 20;
[A,B] = meshgrid(linspace(min(a), max(a), ngrid), ...
                 linspace(min(b), max(b), ngrid));
M = [ones(numel(A),1), A(:), B(:), A(:).^2, A(:).*B(:), B(:).^2];
C2_fit = reshape(M * k2, size(A)); % = k2(1) + k2(2)*A + k2(3)*B + k2(4)*A.^2 + ...

%plot to compare fit with original data
surfl(A,B,C2_fit);shading flat;colormap gray
hold on
plot3(a,b,c, '.r')
```

A 3rd-order fit can be done using the formula given by TryHard below, but the formulas quickly become tedious when the order increases. Better write a function that can construct `M` given `x`, `y` and `order` if you have to do that more than once.

Comment: +1 -- third order fit with `M = [ones(size(x)), x, y, x.^2, x.*y, y.^2, x.^3, x.^2.*y, x.*y.^2, y.^3]` does a pretty good job...

Comment: Sorry for late response! Thankyou for replying Bas Swinckels and Try hard. Nice solution. But, is there any method to find a the best fit formula/equation through code or by using any tool in MATLAB? How one find a formula that best fits above given set of data?

Comment: I am getting this warning as well. Warning: Rank deficient, rank = 5,  tol = 9.9961e-013. Could you please help me understand what this means? Thank you.

Comment: Googling for any combination of polyfit, 2D, 3D, fit, matlab, etc., turns up a lot of answers, that is what I always do for problems I don't know. For sure you will find some recipes on the [file-exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/). But you will have to do that yourself, we are not here to do all your (home)work ...

Comment: You said that you only gave a small portion of your data, try to fit to the whole dataset and see if that changes anything. The data you provided only have 2 distinct values for `a` (0.001 and 0.0011), so trying to fit that with a 2nd order polynomial is ill-undefined ...

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like more of a philosophical question than specific implementation, specifically to bit - "how does one find a formula that fits a set of data to the best advantage?" In my experience that is a *choice* you have to make depending on what you're trying to achieve.

What defines "best" for you? For a data fitting problem you can keep adding more and more polynomial coefficients and making a better R^2 value... but will eventually "over fit" the data. A downside of high order polynomials is behavior outside the bounds of the sample data which you've used to fit your response surface - it can quickly go off in some wild direction which may not be appropriate for whatever it is you're trying to model.

Do you have insight into the physical behavior of the system / data you're fitting? That can be used as a basis for what set of equations to use to create a math model. My recommendation would be to use the most economical (simple) model you can get away with.