# Fitting "quadratic" surface to data points in 3D

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, 3d, data-fitting

I am trying to fit a quadratic plane to a cloud of data points in python. My plane function is of the form

```
   f(x,y,z) = a*x**2 + b*y**2 + c*x*y + d*x + e*y + f - z
```

Currently, my data points do not have errors associated with them, however, some errors can be assumed if necessary. Following suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118419/wrong-result-for-best-fit-plane-to-set-of-points-with-scipy-linalg-lstsq/35118683), I work out the vertical distance from a point p0=(x0,y0,z0) (which correspond to my data points) to a point on the plane p=(x,y,z) following [this method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html). I then end up with

```
def vertical_distance(params,p0):
    *** snip ***
    nominator = f + a*x**2 + b*y**2 + c*x*y - x0*(2*a*x-c*y-d) - y0*(2*b*y-c*x-e) + z0
    denominator = sqrt((2*a*x+c*y+d)**2 + (2*b*y+c*x+e)**2 + (-1)**2)
    return nominator/denominator
```

Ultimately, I think it is the vertical_distance function that I need to minimise. I can happily feed a list of starting parameters (params) and the array of data points to it in two dimensions, however, I am unsure on how to achieve this in 3D. ODR pack seems to only allow data containing x,y or two dimensions. Furthermore, how do I implement the points on the plane (p) into the minimising routine? I guess that during the fit operations the points vary according to the parameter optimisation and thus the exact equation of the plane at that very moment.

Comment: Those links are for linear planes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that «quadratic surface» would be a more correct term than «plane».

And the problem is to fit z = a*x^2 + b*y^2 + c*x*y + d*x + e*y + f
to given set of points P.

To do that via optimization you need to formulate residual function (for instance, vertical distance).

For each 3D points p from P residual is

|p_2 – a*p_0^2 + b*p_1^2 + c*p_0*p_1 + d*p_0 + e*p_1 + f|

You need to minimize all residuals, i.e. sum of square of them, variating parameters a…f.

The following code technically should solve above problem. But fitting the problem is multi-extremal and such routine may fail to find right set of parameters without good starting point or globalization of search.

```
import numpy
import scipy.optimize

P = numpy.random.rand(3,10) # given point set

def quadratic(x,y, a, b, c, d, e, f): 
  #fit quadratic surface
  return a*x**2 + b*y**2 + c*x*y + d*x + e*y + f

def residual(params, points):
  #total residual
  residuals = [
    p[2] - quadratic(p[0], p[1],
    params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4], params[5]) for p in points]

  return numpy.linalg.norm(residuals)

result = scipy.optimize.minimize(residual, 
                                 (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),#starting point
                                 args=P)
```