# Estimating the value based on given data using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently studying numerical methods with python, and i've got a problem with the implementation of some mathematical logic. Suppose i have a table:

data:

```
        x = 0    x = 2    x =  4 
_______________________________
y = 0 | 100.0    90.0     80.0
y = 2 | 85.0     64.49    53.50
y = 4 | 70 48.   90       38.43
```

out of this data, how can i predict the value when x = 4 and y = 3.5 ?

I just need to predict the value within the range of data in the table. How can I do this? Any suggestions will be much appreciated.. thanks :)

Comment: Prediction requires a model.  IE, how do your samples reflect the underlying reality.  You will need to answer that question first.  Then someone can help you code a way to calculate what is needed based on the model.

Comment: not pretty sure if i understand the model, but the data in the table shows the the variation of temperature of a heated plate at various points (x,y), so i want to estimate the temperature in certain point inside the range given in table.

Comment: So you are assuming a linear relationship between sample points?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html

Comment: @StephenRauch probably , and also the temperature having inverse relationship with the x&y coordinates

Comment: @Alexander thanks for linking documentation, sounds interesting :)

Comment: Linear does not care about inverse, that is just a negative sign.  If linear follow Alexander's link. If pandas is a bit much (it can be overwhelming, but it is awesome) then maybe scipy here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

Comment: @StephenRauch ohhh , yeah ur right ..thank you :) i'll look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fit a function `f(x,y) = z` where `z` is the value in the table and `(x,y)` are the x and y values in your table -- a fit in 3 dimensions.

This post [3D curvefitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552011/3d-curvefitting/18648210#18648210)
and this code https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/1db8d69b4b65e8bc66a6 should provide examples of how to do this in python. The code includes implementations for a linear and quadratic fit. You'll want to choose the type of fit based on the data you are working with.